# Assigning values from one row to multiple rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to assign the values from a single row in a DataFrame to multiple rows. I have a DF def_security where the first row looks like this (the column headers are AGG and SPY, and the row index is the date)

```
                   AGG    SPY 
2006-01-01          95     21
```

The rest of the DF all have zeros.

```
                   AGG    SPY 
2006-01-02          0      0
...........
```

I would like to assign the same value as the first row (the values are calculated and not assigned scalars) to the next 250 rows of def_security.  The column headers are user-input and the number of columns or the column headers are not pre-defined.  However, there are same number of columns in each row

I am trying with the code

```
def_security.iloc[1:251] = def_security.iloc[0]
```

but it is returning error msg "could not broadcast input array from shape(250) into shape (250,2)".
What is the easiest way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly right :-)

Try this:

```
def_security.iloc[1:251] = def_security.iloc[0].values
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this code would work:

```
def_security.iloc[1:251,-2]=def_security.iloc[0].at['AGG']
def_security.iloc[1:251,-1]=def_security.iloc[0].at['SPY']
```